# Is there any way of scrubbing notebooks pre-save?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I work with sensitive data and need my notebook to scrub the outputs of cells before saving. I know that this is possible in Jupyter notebooks, but is this also possible in VScode Jupyter?

[Here's the link to the example in the Jupyter docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/savehooks.html#examples), where a `scrub_output_pre_save` function is written and inserted into the `jupyter_notebook_config.py`-file.

Thanks!